# redirect 301 depending on parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

With the restructuring and enhancement of an Website I need to redirect all existing (old) Links to the new structure:

But it needs to be depending on the URL Parm and then redirected with the same parm to a different subdirectory.

somthing like this

```
http://existing_url.com/?m=4&s=5&a=2&b=2&c=3#2
http://existing_url.com/subdirectory/?m=4&s=5&a=2&b=2&c=3#2
```

but I only need to redirect if the parm starts with   **?m=**
as their is new stuff as well...

thx-Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m= [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /subdirectory/ [L,R=302]
```

Query string will be automatically carried over to new target.